# PHP pecl inclued: How to compile and install very latest version

Tags: php, pecl, inclued

The installible versions of the pecl extension 'inclued' apparently are incompatible with the latest versions of PHP (I'm using 5.5.9).  A bug report has been [filed](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65624) and a fix with updated sources noted.  Through svn, I have downloaded the updated files.  How do I compile the very latest sources and install them?

This is on a standard EC2 ubuntu instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit more googling found the following:

http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php

Gives fairly straightforward directions on compiling and installing a pecl extenstion.

The makefile name wasn't quite the same and had to use 'php -i' to find the extension directory.  Also, restarted apache. But seems to be installed.